# access to places api from a cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-places-api

as part of my firebase app, I'm using a cloud function to get data from google places API.
for some reason, I'm getting 403 errors when trying to retrieve data, even though the service account I'm using is the default one (App Engine default service account with Editor role) which seems to exist on the API credentials list and also on the specific cloud function I'm using.

here's the code I'm using to retrieve data from the API -

```
class GoogleMapsRestApiClass {
  client = new Client({});

  getPlaceInfo(placeId: string) {
    return this.client.placeDetails({
      params: {
        place_id: placeId,
        fields: ["name", "rating", "geometry", "photo"],
        key: environment.googleMapsJsApi.apiKey
      }
    } as PlaceDetailsRequest);
  }
}
export const GoogleMapsRestApi = new GoogleMapsRestApiClass();
```

and the cloud function itself -

```
export const place = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
  const placeId = request.query.place_id as string;
  const resp: AxiosResponse = await GoogleMapsRestApi.getPlaceInfo(placeId);
  const result = resp.data.result;
  response.send({result});
});
```

any ideas what I'm missing here?

**Update -**
if I'm not restricting the API key I do manage to retrieve the data (restricted it to my host address).
how should I protect the API key being used by cloud function?

Comment: You forgot type ";" in a 96 line in `places-api.js` file.

Comment: not sure I've understood. i'm using the google-maps-services-js library to retrieve the data

Comment: It was just sarcasm to suggest you haven't entered any code. All we can do is to tell you read documentation about when API returns 403 error code.

Comment: What placeDetails method do ? Why you have no Try catch block?

Comment: it's retrieving "name", "rating", "geometry", "photo" of specific place based on it's id. didn't bother adding yet try-catch block since I'm still testing stuff and want to resolve the issue I'm having first

Comment: Try catch block is a tool to resolve issues. XD

Comment: Hi @gil Have you found the solution to your problem?